# What is the meaning of '*' and '&'?

Tags: go

I am doing the http://tour.golang.org/. Could anyone explain this function to me **lines 1,3,5 and 7**, especially what '*' and '&' do? By mentioning them in a function declaration, what are they supposed/expected to do? A toy example:

```golang
    1: func intial1(var1 int, var2 int, func1.newfunc[]) *callproperfunction {
    2:
    3:    addition:= make ([] add1, var1)
    4:    for i:=1;i<var2;i++ {
    5:       var2 [i] = *addtother (randomstring(lengthofcurrent))
    6:    }
    7:    return &callproperfunction {var1 int, var2 int, func1.newfunc[], jackpot}
    8: }
```

It seems that they are pointers like what we have in C++. But I cannot connect those concepts to what we have here. In other words, what '*' an '&' do when I use them in function declaration in Go.

I know what reference and dereference mean. I cannot understand how we can use a pointer to a function in Go? For example lines 1 and 7, what do these two lines do? The function named intial1 is declared that returns a pointer? And in line 7, we call it with arguments using the return function.

Comment: Those _are_ pointers like we have in C++.

Comment: They are pointers. You can visit https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/8 
for more information about pointers.

Comment: @turhanco, I know they are pointers. but for example what line 5 and 7 do? they are function not variable.

Comment: @David, your example doesn't look like a valid Go code. Write a proper example, ideally which can be run on golang.org. But in any case, Go pointers are pretty much the same as in C++. You get a pointer with `&` and dereference it with `*`. `*` is also used to declare pointer type. Just like in C++.

Comment: @creker, My problem is in lines 1 and 7 in which callproperfunction is used but I cannot understand what these two lines do.

Comment: @David, I don't understand them either. I don't know what are `callproperfunction`, `addtother`, `randomstring`, `lengthofcurrent`, Line 7 doesn't look like Go code at all. `func1.newfunc[]` also doesn't look like Go. Write a proper example that works and can be executed at golang.org.

Comment: @David, regarding functions. Go supports first class functions. It means that you can pass them as arguments, return them, store in collections etc. But you can't take a pointer to a function. When you write `foo := initial1`, `foo` will already be equal to the address of `initial1`. So `&` and `*` doesn't work with functions. Check out this https://golang.org/doc/codewalk/functions/

Answer (score 262, accepted):

This is possibly one of the most confusing things in Go.  There are basically 3 cases you need to understand:

**The `&` Operator**

`&` goes in front of a variable when you want to get that variable's *memory address*.

**The `*` Operator**

`*` goes in front of a variable that holds a memory address and resolves it (it is therefore the counterpart to the `&` operator).  It goes and gets the thing that the pointer was pointing at, e.g. `*myString`.

```
myString := "Hi"
fmt.Println(*&myString)  // prints "Hi"
```

or more usefully, something like

```
myStructPointer = &myStruct
// ...
(*myStructPointer).someAttribute = "New Value"
```

**`*` in front of a Type**

When `*` is put in front of a *type*, e.g. `*string`, it becomes part of the type declaration, so you can say "this variable holds a pointer to a string". For example:

```
var str_pointer *string
```

So the confusing thing is that the `*` really gets used for 2 separate (albeit related) things.  The star can be an operator *or* part of a type.

Comment: I think fmt.Println(*&String) should be fmt.Println(*&myString) . Other than that: nice explanation.

Comment: @Everett I think for * in front of a Type, you should have given solid example similar to other two cases.

Comment: Why `Golang` did this ? Are there any benefits to doing this pointer/address thing instead of using the variable names directly ?

Answer (score 59):

Your question doesn't match very well the example given but I'll try to be straightforward.

Let's suppose we have a variable named `a` which holds the integer 5 and another variable named `p` which is going to be a pointer.
This is where the `*` and `&` come into the game.

Printing variables with them can generate different output, so it all depends on the situation and how well you use.
The use of `*` and `&` can save you lines of code (**that doesn't really matter in small projects**) and make your code more beautiful/readable.

`&` returns the **memory address** of the following variable.

`*` returns the **value** of the following variable (which **should** hold the memory address of a variable, unless you want to get weird output and possibly problems because you're accessing your computer's RAM)

```
var a = 5
var p = &a // p holds variable a's memory address
fmt.Printf("Address of var a: %p\n", p)
fmt.Printf("Value of var a: %v\n", *p)

// Let's change a value (using the initial variable or the pointer)
*p = 3 // using pointer
a = 3 // using initial var

fmt.Printf("Address of var a: %p\n", p)
fmt.Printf("Value of var a: %v\n", *p)
```

All in all, when using * and & in remember that * is for setting the value of the variable you're pointing to and & is the address of the variable you're pointing to/want to point to.

Hope this answer helps.

Comment: simply saying & will point to variable that has no value while * will point to variable that has value in there

Answer (score 18):

Those *are* pointers like we have in C++.

The differences are:

- Instead of `->` to call a method on a pointer, you *always*  use `.`, i.e. `pointer.method()`.
- There are no dangling pointers. It is perfectly valid to return a pointer to a local variable. Golang will ensure the lifetime of the object and garbage-collect it when it's no longer needed.
- Pointers can be created with `new()` or by creating a object `object{}` and taking the address of it with `&`.
- Golang does not allow pointer-arithmetic (arrays do not decay to pointers) and insecure casting. All downcasts will be checked using the runtime-type of the variable and either `panic` or return false as second return-value when the instance is of the wrong type, depending on whether you actually take the second return type or not.

Comment: Also by default Go does not allow pointer arithmetic and casting (type conversion) between incompatible types. And I would say pointers in Go are more like references in Java/C# than pointers in C++

Comment: There are no casts in Go — it has type conversions.

Comment: (My closest comparison point for Go pointers is C# ValueType pointers. Java and C# _object_ references also add additional capabilities (like virtual methods) and costs (like object headers).)

Comment: @twotwotwo, object references are like interfaces in Go. They also has support for dynamic dispatch and additional cost (interface value also has a pointer to the underlying type)

Comment: @creker Yep, all true.

Answer (score 15):

This is by far the easiest way to understand all the three cases as explained in the @Everett answer

```
func zero(x int) {
  x = 0
}
func main() {
  x := 5
  zero(x)
  fmt.Println(x) // x is still 5
}
```

If you need a variable to be changed inside a function then pass the memory address as a parmeter and use the pointer of this memory address to change the variable permanently.

Observe the use of * in front of int in the example. Here it just represents the variable that is passed as a parameter is the address of type int.

```
func zero(xPtr *int) {
  *xPtr = 0
}
func main() {
  x := 5
  zero(&x)
  fmt.Println(x) // x is 0
}
```

Comment: Atleast give due credit from where you have copied this. [golang-book.com/books/intro/8](https://www.golang-book.com/books/intro/8)

Answer (score 3):

Simple explanation.. its just like, you want to mutate the original value

````
func zero(num *int){  // add * to datatype
  *num = 0 // can mutate the original number
}

i := 5
zero(&i) // passing variable with & will allows other function to mutate the current value of variable```
````

Answer (score 0):

**& Operator**  gets the memory address where as *** Opeartor** holds the memory address of particular variable.