# Is there a disadvantage of using a pointer in a struct?

Tags: pointers, go, struct

I am playing around with mysql and returning the result into an array of structs.

```
type User struct {
    FirstName string
    LastName  string
}
```

Go does not allow nil values as string, but if I make the strings pointers

```
type User struct {
    FirstName *string
    LastName  *string
}
```

then it is allowed and I can parse NULL values from the database into nil strings.

Is there a specific disadvantage of using pointers to allow nil? Any reason why I should work with the more than cumbersome NullString approach?

```
type NullString struct {
    String string
    Valid bool
}
```

Comment: Question: *in your application*, is there a meaningful difference between an empty string and the absence-of-a-string? If not, then stick with non-pointer `string` values and you should coalesce SQL `NULL` values to empty-strings in your database query code or when you read data from the database connection.

Comment: Because Go pointers aren’t like C/C++ pointers (e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38234487/returning-a-pointer-on-stack ) you don’t need to worry about lifetime management at least - but when using pointers you still need to reason about when it’s safe to dereference them. Consider using immutable types that will always have valid string members, for example, to alleviate yourself of that responsibility.

Comment: Not just when to dereference them - you must also consider race conditions (excluding string pointers, since strings are immutable) and GC pressure (values get copied so are generally allocated on the stack, whereas any pointer that escapes will be allocated to the heap and subject to GC).

Comment: Thanks everyone, I’m going with the COALESCE option from MySQL. But question apparently, looking at the downvotes but I’m helped out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The disadvantages are straightforward, but they're mostly also the advantages:

1. There is now a pointer that can be nil.  You may need to handle this case differently (because the pointer might be nil), which means you must write more code.  This is also its advantage: you may need to handle this case differently (for the problem you wish to solve, that is), in which case you need a way to flag "does not exist" separately from "contents are ___".  The ability to set the pointer to nil gives you that distinction.
2. Because there is a pointer involved, you can share the underlying data.  This is also its own advantage.
3. Actually using the data requires one extra level of indirection.  (This one is pure disadvantage—there's no upside here.)

Comment: Also pointers can escape, which requires them to be allocated on the heap, which is subject to GC. The more objects subject to GC, the more time your application spends on GC.

Comment: @Adrian: strings can escape too, so it comes out the same there.

Comment: @Adrian True; I was being specific to the problem-as-presented. If you have simpler data types (eg `int`), the all-disadvantage point #3 often includes extra GC work as well as the extra pointer-following work to use the data.